# Facebook oauth callback and Opera

Tags: facebook, oauth, callback, opera

I have created a facebook app which, after clicking a submit button, asks the user for permissions. If the permissions are given, the user is redirected. This works fine in every browser I tested, except for Opera. Opera just doesn't seem to enter the callback function:

```
$("#perms").click(function(){
    FB.ui( { method: 'oauth' } ,  
        function(response){
            alert('test');
            if (response != false) {
                res = eval('(' + response.session + ')')
            }
        }
    );
});
```

In Opera, I am asked for permissions, but the alert never happens. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a different (newer) way to ask for permissions that works with Opera? I googled this problem but found only one page with a sort of similar problem. Adding the channel.html didn't solve the problem though.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still see this issue on Opera 11.52.
browser.js enabled and updated to the latest version.
channelURL set as described in FB docs.

But! it works if I use gistfile.js (beautified version of all.js) located on my host

Answer (score 0):

Do you have browser.js enabled? We have workarounds against some problems with Facebook's Connect script. Note that the workarounds will only trigger if you run Facebook's script from the "official" location on Facebook's server.

For background, please see my response on [FB.login callback not working on Opera Mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768478/fb-login-callback-not-working-on-opera-mobile-browser/)

Comment: And for details on the 'browser.js' feature please see http://www.opera.com/docs/browserjs/